# How to merge new model after training with the old one?

Tags: nlp, opennlp

I have a model "en-ner-organization.bin" which I downloaded from apache web-site. It's works fine, but I prefer to train it with my organizations database to increase recognition quality. But after I trained "en-ner-organization.bin" with my organization database - the size of model became less that it was. So it seems, it was overwritten with my data.

I see that there is no possibility to re-train existing model, but maybe there is a way to merge models?

If no - I guess I can add my train data into the .train file of original model, so generated model will consists of default data, plus my data from db. But I can't find such file in web.

So, the main question is: **how to keep existing model data and add new data into model**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possibile to merge different models, but it's possible to specify different files to the finder.

From the sinopsys:

`$ bin/opennlp TokenNameFinder
Usage: opennlp TokenNameFinder model1 model2 ... modelN < sentences`